# clojure help me get better with grouping items in a list

Tags: clojure

So I hacked this together but I am sure I have a lot to learn about clojure! I already have the right answer but for me that is just the start. Help me understand lisp better by figuring out the way I should have thought about this problem. I am a traditional OO dev... so lisp is not entering my mind very well.

```
(def v [:a :a :a :b :b :c :c :c])

(def a  (first(partition-by identity v)))
(def b (flatten(rest (partition-by identity v))))
(vec(conj (list b) a))
```

The idea of to get the result I already coded above but not with Frankenstein syntax. I hope you can help me.
The result of my code above is: 
[(:a :a :a) (:b :b :c :c :c)]

Comment: what are you going to achieve ? group starting elements till pointer meets different ?and group rest of other elements ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this function?

```
(defn my-group [[x & _ :as xs]]
  (split-with (partial = x) xs))
```

Let's try the function:

```
user> (my-group [:a :a :a :b :b :c :c :c])
;; => [(:a :a :a) (:b :b :c :c :c)]
user> (my-group ["foo" "foo" "bar" "bar" "bar" "baz" "foo"])
;; => [("foo" "foo") ("bar" "bar" "bar" "baz" "foo")]
```

Comment: what does the & _ mean?

Comment: Generally, `_` stands for variable that is not important. The whole construction `[x & _ :as xs]` is example of [destructuring](http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/07/clojure-destructuring.html). `x` holds value of first element of list, `_` is for ignoring the rest, and `:as xs` binds symbol `xs` to entire list. Destructoring is an important feature in Clojure, it is used very often, so I advise you  learn it, not ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you want something like this:

```
(let [[a & r] (partition-by identity v)]                                                                                                                       
  [a (apply concat r)])
```